# Create Spark DataFrame from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to build a Spark DataFrame from a simple Pandas DataFrame. This are the steps I follow.

```py
import pandas as pd
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({"Letters":["X", "Y", "Z"]})
spark_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
spark_df.printSchema()
```

Till' this point everything is OK. The output is:

> root
>   |-- Letters: string (nullable = true)

The problem comes when I try to print the DataFrame:

```py
spark_df.show()
```

This is the result:

> An error occurred while calling o158.collectToPython. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 5.0 (TID 5, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Error from python worker:
>   Error
>   executing Jupyter command 'pyspark.daemon': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory PYTHONPATH was:
>   /home/roldanx/soft/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/home/roldanx/soft/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/home/roldanx/soft/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.4.0.jar:/home/roldanx/soft/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/home/roldanx/soft/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: No port number in pyspark.daemon's
>   stdout

**These are my Spark specifications:**

SparkSession - hive

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version:
    v2.4.0

Master:
    local[*]

AppName:
    PySparkShell

**This are my venv:**

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=jupyter

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='lab'

**Fact:**

As the error mentions, it has to do with running pyspark from Jupyter. Running it with 'PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7' and 'PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6' works fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Import and initialise findspark, create a spark session and then use the object to convert the pandas data frame to a spark data frame. Then add the new spark data frame to the catalogue. Tested and runs in both Jupiter 5.7.2  and Spyder 3.3.2 with python 3.6.6.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

# Create a spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create pandas data frame and convert it to a spark data frame 
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({"Letters":["X", "Y", "Z"]})
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Add the spark data frame to the catalog
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView('spark_df')

spark_df.show()
+-------+
|Letters|
+-------+
|      X|
|      Y|
|      Z|
+-------+

spark.catalog.listTables()
Out[18]: [Table(name='spark_df', database=None, description=None, tableType='TEMPORARY', isTemporary=True)]
```