# How to get correct schema of Dataframe by ignoring initial column header?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have csv file which does not have header to initial one column because of this I am getting warning when I convert it to spark dataframe saying "CSV header does not conform to the schema".

```
        ,a,b
       1,x,y
       2,x,y
       3,x,y <-- table looks like this (,a,b --> are header).
```

so I want to neglect initial column header and get correct schema.
**P.S:** If I name initial column with any header I will get correct schema.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers look like an index, therefore you should treat them like an index by using the index_col parameter.

Convert pandas df to spark df: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54709925/11971785

```
import pandas as pd
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df_pandas = pd.read_csv(r"...\your_csv.csv", index_col = 0)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView('df_spark')
```

Alternatively you could drop the first line and explicitly specify the header like this:

```
df_spark = spark.read.format("csv")\
.option("header", "false")\
.schema(schema=['x', 'a', 'b'])\
.load("...\PATH_to_your_csv")
```

To create this explicitly specified header list dynamically you could try this:

```
lst_columns = list(spark.textFile("...\PATH_to_your_csv")\
           .mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))\
           .filter(lambda line: len(line)==0).toPandas().iloc[0])
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it in pyspark? currently I am using this syntax to read csv to df data_frame=spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true').load(csv_path)

Comment: I added another aproach (second code snippet) let me know if that worked.

Comment: it works but in my real dataset I have lot of columns can't specify all column name explicitly!!

Comment: you could try to load the first line of the csv and create a list of headers from it, example attached (untested)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to rename the column name if I understood correctly, to do so use below

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed('old_column', 'new_column')
df.show()
```

Comment: if null or "" in the header, your code show warning message
 "WARN CSVHeaderChecker: CSV header does not conform to the schema."
because schema will save null as "_c*" but header still null, so it makes conflct. 
After withColumnRenamed printschema function show changed schema but when call action the warning still show again .